# React Native icons disappear once bundle aws-sdk

Tags: react-native, expo, aws-sdk

I am using the Expo38 Bare workflow. (expo eject)

My app works fine on a simulator and a real iPhone device (MX 11), however, when archiving the app and upload it to Apple Store. All icons disappeared but they display fine on the simulator and run on a real iPhone device.

After a couple of days of investigation, I built an initial expo project like following,
expo init
expo eject
react-native bundle AWS-SDK and other js files
Xcode archive
Upload it to Apple store

Icons display fine, however, when I add "var AWS = require('aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk-react-native');"

The icons are gone. If I took off the above line code, the icons are back.

Regards,
Yun

Comment: The difference when adding "var AWS = require('aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk-react-native');"  this line code is that the main.jsbundle file was getting much bigger.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the way you installed the library. Use npm ..... --save or its equivalent.

Comment: I tried to use npm and did another fresh test with Expo 38. When adding "var AWS = require('aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk-react-native');" this line code and then archive the app and export the app as ipa file in development.  After installing on my real device, icons disappeared, but when using Metro loading or remove the above line code, icons appear fine. That's very weird.